# Jquery Dialog Too Big?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The jquery dialog box is ridiculously huge and I'm not sure why.  Manually setting CSS does not appear to work either.  Click the 'Sign-In' button to see the dialog box.

Here is the site I'm currently working on.

http://crowdfundersecrets.com/wwwteamcrowd/www/index.php

For reference for later as code will change here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TeamCrowdFund</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontkit/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <!--accordion -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="accordion/javascript.js"> </script>
    <link href="accordion/format.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--accordion -->

    <!--Tab -->
    <link href="css/tab-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script>
        //Hide Other Modules.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#signindialog").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              width:400,
              height:200,
                 maxHeight:200,
              modal:true,
              position: {my:"center", at: "center", of: window},
              resizable: false,
              show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 500
              },
              hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 500
              },
              buttons: [{ 
                text: "Sign In",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                } 
              }]
            });

            $('#signin').click(function(){
                $('#signindialog').dialog('open');
                console.log('Opening Sign In Dialog');
            });

            $(".module").each(function( index ) {
                if(!$(this).hasClass('visible')){
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });

            $(".leftNav").click(function(){
                $(".leftNav").each(function(index){
                    //Set every nav item to not have current class
                    $(this).removeClass('current');
                });
                $(this).addClass('current');

                //Because the modules go in sequential order, we can use the number to determine which is which.
                var number = $(this).attr('number');
                var i = 0;
                $(".module").each(function( index ) {
                    i=i+1;
                    if(i==number){
                        $(".module").each(function( index ) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        });
                        $(this).show('slow');
                    }
                });

            });

            //Default Action
            jQuery(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
            jQuery("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
            jQuery(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

            //On Click Event
            jQuery("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
                jQuery("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
                jQuery(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
                jQuery(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
                var activeTab = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
                jQuery(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="signindialog" title="Login" style="height:200px">
        <div>Username:<input type="text" value="" id="usernamelogin"/></div>
        <div>Password:<input type="password" value="" id="passwordlogin"/></div>
    </div>
    <section class="centColl">
        <!--Header -->
        <header>
            <div class="headerMain">
                <h1 class="logo">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/tcf-logo.png" alt=""></a>
                </h1>
                <div class="insdieTip">
                    <a href="insidertips.html" class="orange btnsmall"><span class="tips">Insider Tips</span></a>
                    <span>&nbsp;<a href="#" id="register">Register</a> | <a href="#" id="signin">Sign in</a></span>
                </div>
                <nav class="topnav">
                    <a href="index.php" class="text16">Our System</a>
                    <a href="crowdfunding-news.php" class="text16">Crowdfunding News</a>
                    <a href="services.php">Services</a>
                    <a href="community.php">Community</a>
                    <a href="company.php">Company</a>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </header>
        <!--Header -->
```

Please help me figure out why? I'm not sure what is causing the issue.  I've got this to work on my other sites (dnfinder.com, but not this one for some reason).

Comment: can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: I'll try, give me a sec

Comment: I noticed your effects for `show` and `hide` are not working in either Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Why do you have max-height set to none on `signindialog` ?

Comment: not sure how to make it work in jsfiddle :(

Comment: max height doesn't make a difference when I set it as an option, but I edited the code to include maxHeight:200 so you can see

Comment: It is strange that developer tools shows that the height is set to auto, even though the script shows 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on there, however if you remove the

```
content: "."
```

from jquery-ui.css (line 12)

```
.ui-helper-clearfix:after
```

and then specify a height in the second DIV on the page rather than auto

```
    <div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" 
style="width: 400px; top: 0px; display: block; height: 400px; left: 507.5px;" tabindex="-1"
```

things start to look a bit more normal - hopefully this gives you somewhere to start your analysis from....

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it you were right, the problem was this line.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> , sorry stupid enter sent to early, but I changed the line above to the correct coresponding version of jqueryui, apparently I had them out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer thanks to a post above.

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Notice the CSS version for jquery-ui was outdated...>.>, sorry guys stupid error on my part, but might help someone else who experience the same thing.

Comment: To fix it I just changed the ajax.googleapis css version to 1.10.2 like my jquery-ui version was.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution.

jQueryUI's dialog size is based on the default font-size setting for the document.

If you insert this into your CSS:

```
html{font-size:62.5%}
```

you will solve several problems, including jQueryUI's too-large dialog size. This is because the default font size in most browsers is 16px, which makes for a big dialog.

[jsFiddle Example 1: too large](http://jsfiddle.net/6e44mha3/)

[jsFiddle Example 2: normal size](http://jsfiddle.net/6e44mha3/1/)

**The only diff between the examples is in the CSS.**

Here is why to use 62.5% as font size for html:

[Mozilla - look at EMs section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Possible_approaches)

[Worth Reading](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/62-5-font-size/)